# node_modules/marked/lib/marked.js does not exist. Angular 12

Tags: nodejs, angular, npm

Tengo las siguientes versiones:

Angular CLI: 12.2.4
Node: 12.21.0
Package Manager: npm 6.14.11
OS: win32 x64

Al intentar compilar un proyecto clonado de un repositorio de git me marca lo siguiente:

**npm run build:test**

- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...An unhandled exception occurred: Script file node_modules/marked/lib/marked.js does not exist.
  See "C:\Users\PQUINO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-hwcW58\angular-errors.log" for further details.

Pero en el directorio node_modules\marked\lib si se encuentra el archivo marked.js ya que cuando se clono el proyecto se ejecuto el **npm install** para instalar todas las dependencias y en el archivo package.js contiene lo siguiente:

"marked": "^4.0.12",

*¿Cual será el problema?*

Comment: Es decir, ya hiciste `npm install` localmente? Borra la carpeta `node_modules` y todo su contenido, vuelve a correr `npm install` y luego `npm run build:test`

Comment: Hice lo que dices y ahora marca otro error de una libreria de minimizer css, pero se mira que es problema del proyecto en general y no del ambiente del angular, mejor lo paso al area que lo desarrollo haber si ellos lo corrigen. gracias

Comment: Dale. Recuerda siempre que `/node_modules` lo crea Node cuando instalas todas las dependencias y tal. Lo mismo el `package_lock.json`; son los que dicen realmente cómo va tu proyecto. Son sensibles a la versión de Node y de NPM que uno use, así que no es sano copiar-pegar-clonar esa carpeta (el package-lock en cambio sí).